# Choosing best model regarding to k-fold cross validation

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I want to take Iris data and choose best logistic model based on GridSearchCV function.

**My work so far**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]
y = iris.target

# Logistic regression 
reg_log = LogisticRegression()

# Penalties
pen = ['l1', 'l2','none']

#Regularization strength (numbers from -10 up to 10)
C = np.logspace(-10, 10, 100)

# Possibilities for those parameters
parameters= dict(C=C, penalty=pen)

# choosing best model based on 5-fold cross validation
Model = GridSearchCV(reg_log, parameters, cv=5)

# Fitting best model
Best_model = Model.fit(X, y)
```

And I get a lot of errors. Do you know maybe what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: can you provide error info, traceback ?

Comment: “I get a lot of errors.”. Please update the question to be more specific.  Remember, we do not have any context of your specific issue - you must fully explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are choosing different regularization, you can see on the [help page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html):

> The ‘newton-cg’, ‘sag’, and ‘lbfgs’ solvers support only L2
> regularization with primal formulation, or no regularization. The
> ‘liblinear’ solver supports both L1 and L2 regularization, with a dual
> formulation only for the L2 penalty. The Elastic-Net regularization is
> only supported by the ‘saga’ solver.

I am not quite sure if you want to do a grid search with penalization = 'none' and penalization scores. So if you use `saga` and increase the iteration:

```
reg_log = LogisticRegression(solver="saga",max_iter=1000)

pen = ['l1', 'l2']
C = [0.1,0.001]

parameters= dict(C=C, penalty=pen)

Model = GridSearchCV(reg_log, parameters, cv=5)

Best_model = Model.fit(X, y)

res = pd.DataFrame(Best_model.cv_results_)
res[['param_C','param_penalty','mean_test_score']]

    param_C param_penalty   mean_test_score
0   0.1 l1  0.753333
1   0.1 l2  0.833333
2   0.001   l1  0.333333
3   0.001   l2  0.700000
```

It works pretty ok. If you get more errors with your penalization values.. try to look at them and make sure they are not some crazy values.